# Something is not right with %r

Tags: python-2.7

Now I am working on LPTHW, for Zed Shaw, and on this example there is something doesn't make any sense to me.

First I assign `formatter = % ( "%r %r %r %r")`,
then I try to pring the formatter.

```
pprint formatter % (
    "I had this thing.",
    "That you could type up right.",
    "But it didn\'t sing.",
    "So I said goodnight.",
)
```

Output: `'I had this thing.' 'That you could type up right.' "But it didn't sing." 'So I said goodnight.'`.

Why does the output have singles quote around the 1st, 2nd, 4th argument but double quotes on the 3rd?

And when I try to assign another variable for the same operation:

```
print formatter % ( 
"Whatever",
"Comes",
"First",
"Go first"
)
```

Output:`'Whatever' 'Comes' 'First' 'Go first'`.

Here all are in single quotes and does make sense. Can anyone tell me what is going on here?

Comment: There's a single quote in your third phrase, so it makes sense to surround that with double quotes: that way, the single quote doesn't need to be escaped. It reads better without a backslash than with the backslash. The single or double quotes around it are just representation anyway, indicating the contents is a string: you shouldn't see the surrounding quotes as part of the contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%r` stands for `%repr` And is supposed to carry on detailed information. 
Such as in your code:

```
First I assign formatter = % ( "%r %r %r %r")

print formatter % ( 1, 2, 3, 4 )
print formatter % (
    "I had this thing.",
    "That you could type up right.",
    "But it didn\'t sing.",
    "So I said goodnight.",
)
```

Output:

```
 1 2 3 4
'I had this thing.' 'That you could type up right.' "But it didn't sing." 'So I said goodnig'
```

Now, notice the first line prints without any quotes as it suppose to, its detailing this is integers. While on the 2nd output its detailing there is 1st phrase and its surrounded with quotes to indicate that its string

Why does the output have singles quote around the 1st, 2nd, 4th argument but double quotes on the 3rd?
And when I try to assign another variable for the same operation.

Because in the 3rd phrase you've single quote used in the word `don't` so the interpreter is quoting the phrase with double quotes even when you assign the string with single quote is to tell you hey this is string and have single quote/escape character inside.

Note: even if you used escape character for the single quote or not it is going to be double quote and this is exactly what %repr supposed to do. For more information check [repr() implementation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/repr.html)